# Sacar primer elemento bucle php (loop wordpress) y utilizarlo en javascript

Tags: php, wordpress

¿Como puedo sacar el the_title() del primer post que recorre el while y después extraerlo para utilizarlo en las funciones de javascript?
el primer the_title() es plan, pero quiero evitar hardcodearlo ya que podría ser actualizado en un futuro.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function onload(){
    // primer elemento.id hardcodeado
    document.getElementById('plan').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var sw=0;
var anterior="";
function show(objeto){  
    if (objeto!=anterior){
        // primer elemento.id hardcodeado
        document.getElementById('plan').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(objeto).style.display = 'block';
        if (sw==1){
            document.getElementById(anterior).style.display = 'none';   
        }
        anterior=objeto;
        sw=1;
    }
}   
</script>

<?php
query_posts("category_name=x" . "&order=asc" . "&posts_per_page=-1");
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'contetn', 'page' );
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: No soy muy amigo de wordpress pero se me ocurre un enfoque por otro lado, porque no intentas obtener el titulo una vez ya esta todo el html renderizado? como quedaria la estructura del html una vez la pagina esta cargada? si agregas como queda el html final, podría ver de darte una solución por ese lado si es que te interesa, saludos!

Comment: faltaría el código de content.php y content-page.php si es que estan separados, estos varían entre themes por ejemplo el `Twenty Fifteen 1.0` usa tags h1 para single posts y pages, y h2 para listados, la clase que le aplica es `.entry-title` asi que con jquery podrias capturar el primero (h1 o h2) que contenga esa clase. pero todo depende de como se maneje el theme con los templates